# Docker Volumes - Changes not reflected

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

*Using node.js*

I am having an issue with docker volumes. I set up a volume in my docker-compose.yml file, but for some reason, changes I am making locally are not being reflected. Any idea why?

I have the current docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  posts:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./posts
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./posts:/app
  ...// more services here
```

Excerpt from index.js in posts

```
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Quackss!");
  res.send(posts);
});
```

Now lets say I run

```
docker-compose up --build posts
```

When I make my first request via postman to /posts
I see "Quackss!" in my console.

Now when I change the code to

```
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Double Quack");
  res.send(posts);
});
```

and save, then make a request via postman
I still see "Quacks!!" instead of "Double Quack".

I do have nodemon setup, so I didn't think that was the issue.

I ran `docker ps` to see the name of the container
Then ran `docker exec -it <container name> sh`
then `cat index.js`
If volumes were setup correctly, I'd expect to see

```
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Double Quack");
  res.send(posts);
});
```

Instead, I saw the original

```
app.get("/posts", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Quackss!");
  res.send(posts);
});
```

Here is my posts package.json

```
{
  "name": "posts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

And dockerfile.dev

```
FROM    node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app/
COPY    ./package.json ./
RUN     npm install
COPY    ./ ./
CMD     ["npm", "start"]
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You are mapping your volume to /app, but you are placing your code in the container in /usr/app. Thus the code you are running and the code you have mounted are not the same. Try mounting your volume to /usr/app instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dockerfile.dev` has a `WORKDIR` of `/usr/app/` and you're copying the source code into that directory.
Your `docker-compose.yml` file is mapping the volumes to `/app` instead.

One solution is to change the `WORKDIR` to `/app/` and rebuild your image.

Comment: doesn't work for me